# 'See him told' versus 'See that he is told'

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I'm curious if both of these mean the same thing:

> *I always see him told to do the same thing.*
>
> *I always see that he is told to do the same thing.*

If not, can you please tell me what the difference is?

Comment: Excellent question. Here's hoping for a linguist or serious enthusiast of English to give you a decent answer!

Comment: @Araucaria With that rep, I assume you are at least one of those :)

Comment: @Joachim Possibly. But if so, a very busy one!

Comment: What research have you done yourself, So? For a start, can you give attributed links to examples of these usages? Is it the 'see = ensure' or 'see = observe' sense you are thinking about? Dictionaries will doubtless give them both.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is a grammar which the teachers in my country call "complex object" (the 1st example). But every time i try to search for that in the internet i come across articles in my language which can't really explain the difference between such sentences as above. I guess "see" means observe in this case.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would interpret the first as 'I witness him being told' and the second as 'I make sure that he is told'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Though the first sentence doesn't sound very natural, I go with your readings. But OP should show (link & attribute) the candidate definitions of 'see' and 'see that'. [The Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+that) covers the latter well.

Comment: The teachers in your country are mistaken. **The first sentence sounds very contrived**. It would seem they might mean: **I always see him being told to do the same thing**. versus this other passive: **I always see that he is told to do the same thing**. [Writing a grammar about a  language that is not one's own is a very tricky business.] Now, one can compare them rationally.

Comment: See him told = Like one sees him 'told' - being told/ having been told/ to have been told.  It could be anything. It can be interpreted as "See that he is told." The meaning may differ based on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's first example is *probably* intended to mean...

> 1: *What I always see is that he is told to do the same thing.*
>    ...or more accurately,...
>    2: *What I see is that he is always told to do the same thing.*

Ignoring that ambiguity about the intended referent of ***always***, there's a completely different meaning that's more likely to be conveyed by OP's *second* example...

> 3: *I always **see to it that** he is told to do the same thing.*
>   ...or more accurately,...
>    4: *I **see to it / make sure** that he is always told to do the same thing.*

Note that these are just *likely* intended meanings. In principle, either of OP's versions could validly be used with either sense.